# hibernate reverse engineering identity column

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, reverse-engineering, identity-column

I have a legacy database at SQL Server 2008 and I would like to use Hibernate ORM.
So I tried reverse engineering by using jboss tools eclipse kepler.
But my problem is pojo class generation.

I have tables which are using integer auto-incremented columns in legacy databse.
But my pojo classes are generated without having identity columns.
So according to [this tutorial](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/HandlingIDENTITYColumnsInCustomReverseEngineeringConfigWithHbm2javaAndSeamgen), I can make it correct to set identity columns.

```
<primary-key><generator class="identity"/></primary-key>
```

But my question is do I always need to write that additional xml tag ?
What if I have 99 out of 100 tables are using integer auto-incremented colums in legacy database ?
What if my development team need to update legacy database tables again, and generate pojo again?

Then it will be made many duplicate manual input again and again.

Could anyone please give me any more better solution?

Answer (score 0):

in hibernate reverse engering configuration you can define the type transformtaions like :

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
<type-mapping>
 <sql-type jdbc-type="BIGINT" length='20' hibernate-type="Long" /> 
</type-mapping>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

[Jboss Reference Link](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html)